# Select top 3 records from column

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to select TOP 3 records from column "score", with highiest number. For example:

record1:
column score: 12

record2:
column score: 23

record3:
column score: 0

record4:
column score: 5

record5:
column score: 2

Sql would return : 23,12,5.

Is this possible?

Comment: What type of SQL provider are you using? MySQL? MS SQL Server? SQLite?

Comment: What if there are duplicate high scores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 score from score_table order BY score desc
```

Comment: @rootpanthera, right, I forgot about the time limit. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 3 Score from *your_table_name* ORDER BY your_score_column_name DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT score FROM table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```